# Debug from Django admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I'm trying to have a print statement appear on the console every time I add data into my Postgres Database (For example "Post succeeded") from the Django admin but no matter where I put print statements (in admin.py or the models) nothing is appearing. I know the data is going through as there is a POST statement that goes through [image: example of post going through]
and the data is in the database.

Comment: do yourself a favor and download a nice ide like pycharm... (im gonna take a stab in the dark that you are a student, so get the free pro version for students), create a new django project, use breakpoints and debug like a superstar (I think if you set `DEBUG=True` in your settings you will see your normal stdout as well ... but im not sure ... admin may handle it different)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Admin object, you can put a `print` statement in the `save_model()` method. It sounds like that's where it will best suit you if you want to print something after adding data.

It would look something like this:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print('Post succeeded')
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```